# Facebook SDK's FBProfilePictureView display too small

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a frustrating problem that I can seem to work out.

- I have a view which I subclassed in storyboard into a `FBProfilePictureView` around 125x125.
- Once I retrieve the user graph object using the Facebook API I then set the profile picture view's `Profile Id` property to that of the user.
- The profile picture is displayed but only in an area that must be around 20x20 square.

I have tried searching around for a reason it keeps doing this but I can't see anything about the latest SDK its all the old one.

If you need anymore information just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the image from facebook graph and put it on a UIImageView like this:

```
-(void) getUserImageWithProfileId:(NSString *)profileId{

    int imgWidth = 125;
    int imgHeight = 125;

    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture?width=%d&height=%d",profileId,imgWidth,imgHeight];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/"]];
    [client getPath:urlPath parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id data) {

        UIImage *imageFromURL = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        //HERE DO ANITHING WITH THE UIIMAGE, you can put it on a UIImageView or something

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //fail
    }]; 
}
```

you need download the [AFNetworking Framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to do the http request, this code is with ARC, if your project don´t use it make the `client` autoreleased and put the flag on AFNetworking libs (in the link describe how do that)